# not able to push to git using ssh

Tags: git, push, ssh-keys

I have configured ssh communication with my github using ssk key.
I have followed the instructions in https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

I did the test with success: ssh -T git@github.kyndryl.net
Hi joaopedro! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I can see my repository was pushed: git remote -v
WASAdmin    https://github.kyndryl.net/joaopedro/WASAdmin (fetch)
WASAdmin    https://github.kyndryl.net/joaopedro/WASAdmin (push)

But I do not see any file in the git site.

Comment: The URLs in your remote are using https, not ssh.

Comment: I saw in another porst that I should do the following: git remote set-url --push WASAdmin 'git@github.kyndryl.net:joaopedro/WASAdmin.git
> 
But a prompt appears to me and nothing happens!

Comment: @StephenNewell , so what am I missing?! I added the ssh key to git already.

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem. Some commands were missing:
git remote set-url WASAdmin   git@github.kyndryl.net:joaopedro/WASAdmin.git
git add -A
git commit -am "Update README.MD"
git push --set-upstream WASAdmin master

And the result was:
Enumerating objects: 414, done.
Counting objects: 100% (414/414), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (403/403), done.
Writing objects: 100% (414/414), 21.79 MiB | 3.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 414 (delta 172), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (172/172), done.
remote: detect-secrets-stream ver=manual-kyndryl-manual-kyndryl FAQ: https://pages.github.kyndryl.net/river/detect-secrets-pages
remote:
remote: Successfully send push metadata.
remote: Push info collect pre-receive hook finished within 3 seconds.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.kyndryl.net/joaopedro/WASAdmin/pull/new/master
remote:
To github.kyndryl.net:joaopedro/WASAdmin.git

- [new branch]      master -> master
  Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'WASAdmin'.

Comment: This is trivially obvious and so is probably not a useful question-and-answer. If, however, you wish to leave your question and answer on stack overflow, then please format them properly.

Comment: It can be obvious to someone that has experience with this subject, but not for a dummy person like me. I think that for dummies that are looking for answers to have them consolidated here is good. Why I made the question at the first place? Because I did not find help before, anywhere. I had to dig and dig until I found it. So let this answer help others like me, please.